# Gosu compiler: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: Internal Gosu compiler exception

Tags: jar, guidewire

We are trying upgrade spring web, spring core, spring bean framework from 5.* version to Version 6* in Billing center with V10. But getting below Exception :
Gosu compiler: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: Internal Gosu compiler exception.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

we are using Java 11 while upgrading the spring framework, Is there any way to upgrade spring framework without switching to java 17 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 6 based on Java 17+

You should extract your Spring part from BC and develop it independently

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the Guidewire platform and seems to be relevant to the version of Spring you are using.
According to GA announcement from Spring - https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga it's baselined with Java 17+ which is exactly what the error you are getting points to - probably coming from your spring jar(s).

So, I think the only sensible option for you is to stay with v5 of spring as it is baselined for JDK v9.

v5.3 seems to be the latest official branch before v6 - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions